# How do I install the Python library found here: https://github.com/DonoA/PyAnvilEditor?

Tags: python, github, pip

Simple question. How do I install a Python library found on GitHub here: https://github.com/DonoA/PyAnvilEditor Any help would be greatly appreciated (:

Answer (score 0):

I see that this repository is not published with a python package index. So you cannot use `pip install`  for installing this.
One way is to download the source code and use the files in the directory [pyanvil](https://github.com/DonoA/PyAnvilEditor/tree/master/pyanvil).

You can `import nbt, world, stream` and so on of this project if you have those files `nbt.py` , `world.py`, `stream.py` in the same folder as your source code.

Comment: pyanvil is not only a directory, it is a package. Also pip will install from many sources, including git. However the pyanvil project is not well maintained and is missing a `setup.py` file. So pip cannot install from that location.